# Is there a mathematical notation to express the domain without the range or the range without the domain?

Tags: notation

According to the [domain's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function)

I can express the domain and range of a function like this $$f:X\rightarrow Y$$

What if I am only interested in the domain of the function? Is it mathematically accepted to write this?
$$f:X$$

What if I am only interested in the range?

I am asking if there is a mathematical notation to represent these concepts individually without presenting both at the same time.

Comment: The range of $f$ is often expressed by $f(X).$ However, as you can see, it still uses the fact that $X$ is the domain of $f.$

Comment: Looking through a book I have found the notation $D_{f}$ and $R_{f}$. Is this widely used?

Comment: Actually, $Y$ is the codomain, which is a superset of the range.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One often sees 
$\operatorname{dom }f$ and $\operatorname{ran} f$ or $D(f)$ and $R(f)$ or $D_{f}$ and $R_{f}$ .

Of course, you can also say something like

> When $f$ is a function, we will write “$\square f$” to mean the domain of $f$ and “$f\square$” to mean the codomain

or whatever. You're allowed to make up whatever notation you like, as long as you explain it clearly.

Comment: Is that supposed to appear as a white box?

Comment: The $\square$ is supposed to appear as a hollow square.

Comment: Indeed, ◻ is U+25FB: WHITE MEDIUM SQUARE.